# Find all maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> How to find all maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$?

I have no idea because $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed. Is there any good way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any ideal $I$ of $R=\mathbb{R}\left[x,y\right]/\left\langle x^2+y^2\right\rangle$ is of the form $I=I_0/\left\langle x^2+y^2\right\rangle$ for some ideal $\left\langle x^2+y^2\right\rangle\subseteq I_0\vartriangleleft\mathbb{R}\left[x,y\right]$. $I$ is maximal in $R$ if and only if $I_0$ is maximal in $\mathbb{R}\left[x,y\right]$. So your question is equivalent to finding all maximal ideals in $\mathbb{R}\left[x,y\right]$ which contain $\left\langle x^2+y^2\right\rangle$. See [here](http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-algebra/68149-maximal-ideal-r-x-y.html) for the classification of maximal ideals of $\mathbb{R}\left[x,y\right]$.

Comment: Thanks! But why every maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}\left[x,y\right]$ is generated by $f(x),g(x,y)$ ,not $f(x,y),g(x,y)$?